# how to set driver connection properties using c3p0 libraries?

Tags: jdbc, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

I am Migrating from dbcp2 to c3p0,

We create a datasource by extending the BasicDataSource from dbcp2 and setting the properties. Some properties are set at driver level via setConnectionProperties method.

I dont see such a provision in c3p0 when extending the AbstractComboPooledDataSource. Is there another way to set the same?

Digging through the docs, I found something called a connectionCustomizer, but not sure if it does the same

This is how I am currently setting the properties with dbcp2:

```
this.setConnectionProperties("driver:oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=180000");
this.setConnectionProperties("driver:oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=180000");
```

where "this" is class which extends BasicDataSource

Is there anyway in c3p0 to get the same result?

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I am able to set the properties provided by the c3p0 library, what I am looking for is setting properties at driver level the way dbcp2 allows to do via the SetConnectionProperties() method.THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this answer:
[c3p0 hangs on getConnection when there is a network failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490719/c3p0-hangs-on-getconnection-when-there-is-a-network-failure).

```
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
...

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// NOTE: Once you decide to use cpds.setProperties() to set some connection properties,
//       all properties must be set, including user/password, otherwise an exception
//       will be thrown
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT",
    Integer.toString(JDBC_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS));
prop.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout",
    Integer.toString(JDBC_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS));
prop.setProperty("user", username);
prop.setProperty("password", password);
cpds.setProperties(prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details from the below answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838455/1529092

So basically you have to do something like this,

```
@Bean
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource(){
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("minPoolSize")));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxPoolSize")));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxIdleTime")));
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatements")));
        dataSource.setMaxStatementsPerConnection(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("maxStatementsPerConnection")));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(10000);

    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

**Edit:**

As per [documentation](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), the timeout properties are different in each framework, so in this case, the time out is handled by,

- maxConnectionAge
- maxIdleTime
- maxIdleTimeExcessConnections

> **Managing Pool Size and Connection Age Go To Top**
>
> Different applications have different needs with regard to trade-offs
>   between performance, footprint, and reliability. C3P0 offers a wide
>   variety of options for controlling how quickly pools that have grown
>   large under load revert to minPoolSize, and whether "old" Connections
>   in the pool should be proactively replaced to maintain their
>   reliablity.
>
> - maxConnectionAge
> - maxIdleTime
> - maxIdleTimeExcessConnections
>
> By default, pools will never expire Connections. If you wish Connections to be expired over time in order
>   to maintain "freshness", set maxIdleTime and/or maxConnectionAge.
>   maxIdleTime defines how many seconds a Connection should be permitted
>   to go unused before being culled from the pool. maxConnectionAge
>   forces the pool to cull any Connections that were acquired from the
>   database more than the set number of seconds in the past.
>
> maxIdleTimeExcessConnections is about minimizing the number of
>   Connections held by c3p0 pools when the pool is not under load. By
>   default, c3p0 pools grow under load, but only shrink if Connections
>   fail a Connection test or are expired away via the parameters
>   described above. Some users want their pools to quickly release
>   unnecessary Connections after a spike in usage that forces a large
>   pool size. You can achieve this by setting
>   maxIdleTimeExcessConnections to a value much shorter than maxIdleTime,
>   forcing Connections beyond your set minimum size to be released if
>   they sit idle for more than a short period of time.
>
> Some general advice about all of these timeout parameters: Slow down!
>   The point of Connection pooling is to bear the cost of acquiring a
>   Connection only once, and then to reuse the Connection many, many
>   times. Most databases support Connections that remain open for hours
>   at a time. There's no need to churn through all your Connections every
>   few seconds or minutes. Setting maxConnectionAge or maxIdleTime to
>   1800 (30 minutes) is quite aggressive. For most databases, several
>   hours may be more appropriate. You can ensure the reliability of your
>   Connections by testing them, rather than by tossing them. (see
>   Configuring Connection Testing.) The only one of these parameters that
>   should generally be set to a few minutes or less is
>   maxIdleTimeExcessConnections.

Comment: how would you set "driver:oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=180000" in the datasource which you have created? That is what I needed help with.